# Use Google Groups Without Revealing Member Emails

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups, google-apps-for-work

I would like to embed a Google Group for Business Q & A forum in my website.

My website is based on users not knowing each others' emails addresses.
However, when someone posts a question to the Google Group Q & A forum, all members are sent an email notification where the "from" field is the email address of the poster.
I can't have this since I don't want the users knowing each others' email addresses.

Are there any suggestions for embedding a Google Group Q&A while still keeping member email addresses concealed (can't I send the notification emails from the group email address or something)? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

Settings that affect the From address:

- Settings / Email Options : Post replies  (needs to be set to 'to the entire group')
- Settings / Identity :    Required forms of identity
- Permissions / Access permissions : View Member Email Addresses
- Permissions / Posting permissions : Reply To Author

Set correctly , the from address will show "username via groupname" . 
Can also be set to show "groupname on behalf of username" .

Posting by email to the group should be disabled, otherwise all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a direct way to do this, but the work-around I've seen people do is as follows: the person writing the post to submits it to the moderator's address, who then sends it on to the group.

Comment: I have given up on using google groups because I didn't find a solution to this. I considered an routing all emails to me and then having me forward it out but I only remember that it wasn't possible to have all the group's emails only go to me.

Comment: @theyuv - so, what software did you choose?  How has it worked out for your group?

Comment: I'm currently trying to use wordpress with a plugin to create a q & a forum. I'm not finished with it. It's a lot more work than google groups. Google groups would have been really quick and easy to implement but it had that one flaw of revealing emails that I didn't want.

Comment: @theyuv - please keep me posted.  I am trying to decide right now which route to go for a group of folks I'm involved with.

Comment: found anything? It seems this is still an issue after a few years..